# xlwings: Group data with .expand() vertical instead of horizontal?

Tags: python, xlwings

With the "sht.range('NamedRange').expand()" method it's possible to group data of a given tabe into a nested list.
The data is grouped horizontaly. Is it possible to group the data verticaly with .expand()?

I know it's possible to group the data verticaly with .expand("down") but with this command the expansion is not applied to the whole table.

```py
Example: 

sht.range('A1').value = [[1,2], [3,4]]
rng1 = sht.range('A1').expand().value

Output:
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]

What I'm looking for:

Output:

[[1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to transpose your result. You can do that the following way:

```
>>> sht.range('A1').value = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> rng1 = sht.range('A1').options(expand='table', transpose=True).value
[[1.0, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0]]
```

See also: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#default-converter